# IE tries to download json response when using ajaxForm jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, ajaxform

I've tried everything and don't know what seems to be the problem.

**The problem : IE downloads the json response + before submitting does not fire.**

I'm using IE 11.

I'm using the jQuery - ajaxForm plugin.
Implemented file upload with it.
Everything works perfect with chrome **and everything does not with IE.**

IE tries to download the json response and doesn't do the plugin before function.

The JS code:

```
var options = {
    beforeSend: beforeSubmit,
    uploadProgress: progressSubmit,
    success: uploadSuccess,
    complete: completeSubmmit
};

form.ajaxForm(options);
```

The actual request performed in manual click.

```
('#submitBtn').click();
```

I'm using MVC-3 controller, the HttpPost action receives HttpPostedFile.
The response is a simple ViewModel contains several strings.

I have tried all the following, **nothing worked**.

Attempts :

```
Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
Response.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");

return Json(vm, "text/html");
return Content(JsonSerializerHelper.Serialize(vm), "text/html");
return Json(vm);
```

Fiddler :

***Chrome Request:***

```
Content-Length: 606
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----    WebKitFormBoundary4ABojutLkBGFbphB
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4,ru;q=0.
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="customersBulk.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
```

***Chrome Response :***

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Thu, 29 Jan 2015 18:19:47 GMT
Content-Length: 469

-- and the actual Json object. --
```

***IE Request:***

```
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: he-IL
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7df28b2e1c126c
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 691
DNT: 1
Host: localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";     filename="MY_PATH\..\customersBulk.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
-----------------------------7df28b2e1c126c--
```

***IE Response:***

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Thu, 29 Jan 2015 18:15:50 GMT
Content-Length: 558

-- and the Json as well. --
```

Versions:
jQuery Form Plugin

version: 3.50.0-2014.02.05
Requires jQuery v1.5 or later

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try following thing:

```
$('#YourFormId').bind('submit', function() { return false; });
```

This will prevent the original form submission process.